# Open New View in Bootstrap Modal in Django

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-modal

My situation is that I have several modals (4 to be exact) which should be accessible in every single view in my app. I will use just one as an example.  Let's take a look at how I am displaying this on the home screen view:

base.html

```
...abbreviated...

<a data-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModal">Shipment</buton>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create Shipment</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="modal-body">
        {{shipmentForm|crispy}}
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" name="shipment" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the view which passes `shipmentForm` to that template

views.py

```
def HomeView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        shipment_form = CreateShipmentForm(request.POST)
        if shipment_form.is_valid():
            new_shipment = shipment_form.save()the user to the success page
            return redirect('ShipmentListView')

    shipmentForm = CreateShipmentForm()
    context = {
        'shipmentForm': shipmentForm,
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

This works perfectly fine, but the problem is, I would need to include this code from HomeView in every single view in my app. That would be a lot of repeating myself. I have included the html for the modal in my base.html so that I don't have to repeat that.  But instead of what I have above, I'd like to make the button which launches the modal look/do something like this.

base.html

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="{% url 'CreateShipmentView' %}>Shipment</buton>
```

Put the html for the modal form in a separate file:

modal.html

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create Shipment</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="modal-body">
        {{shipmentForm|crispy}}
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" name="shipment" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then have a view like this:

```
def CreateShipmentView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        shipment_form = CreateShipmentForm(request.POST)
        if shipment_form.is_valid():
            new_shipment = shipment_form.save()the user to the success page
            return redirect('ShipmentListView')

    shipmentForm = CreateShipmentForm()
    context = {
        'shipmentForm': shipmentForm,
    }
    return render(request, 'modal.html', context)
```

How is this possible without using django-modal-bootstrap package?  I tried that but it seemed to be very very touchy and I did not like it so would prefer to avoid that.  Can anyone point me in the direction of how I could make this work please?